# Genetic programming for symbolic equation solving

Tags: genetic-algorithm, polynomial-math, equation-solving, genetic-programming, genetics

I'm trying to perform a **genetic programming** system which **solves an equation** (basically **first and second degree polynom equations**) **symboliclly**.

It means that for **a*x+b=0** it must give me a **tree** representation of **-b/a**. What i mean by **symbolically** is that i'm not giving **numbers** for **'a'** and **'b'** ... basically what **Generic Programming are made for**.

I'm actually stuck in finding the **fitness function**. For a given **gene (potential solution)**, how can i **predict** how **far** is **this one** from the **right solution**.

My doubt is that there's no way to do such a thing unless i **convert** the problem into a **numerical** one.

I've been searching in the net, but all i found was related to **genetic algorithms** and so **numerical resolution** for such problem.

a link exposing such topic is found here: [Generic Programming](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~vemuri/classes/ecs271/The%20GP%20Tutorial.htm) but it's not explaining a detailed approach about the problem.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which language are you programming? Most computer algebra systems have a `Solve(a*x+b==0,x)`or an `Eliminate` function.

Comment: I'm programming in Java... look, i know that it's possible to solve a linear or quadratic equation to get a numeric value of x.. but i'm not looking for a numeric result, otherwise i would have implemented that, it requires 1 line of code only... what i was looking for is a GP program to solve the equation and get the formula as a result, like for a linear problem it give -b/a , or for quadratic one it gives (-b + sqrt(b² - 4ac))/(2a) or (-b - sqrt(b² - 4ac))/(2a)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant for example with this Solve function in Java: https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library/blob/master/symja_android_library/doc/functions/Solve.md or https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library/blob/master/symja_android_library/doc/functions/Roots.md

Comment: Maan awesome library, it's just amazing, i checked its brievely and sorry for late answer ... you're created the library using Genetic Programming ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution.

I've found a powerfull library which is designed for Genetic Algorithms for java developpers, and have a module specialized in Genetic Programming (GP).

Library's link: [Jenetics](http://jenetics.io/)

My implementation of the solution is available on my github at this link: [Symbolic Equation Solver](https://github.com/mssm199996/symbolic-equation-solver)

It's basically a Maven based project, which makes use of Java 11 and the above library to solve Linear and Quadratic equations and gives symbolic (and not numeric) result.